# Blazor app puzzling compiler error message on a new page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, .net-standard, blazor-webassembly

I have a simple Blazor page but I'm getting some strange error messages.  I cleaned the solution and rebuild the project but the same error pops up.  This is all started when I copied an existing razor page, pasted and renamed it.  So I deleted the copy and did an `Add New` but still getting four error messages.  One of them is complaining about the `@page "/register"` which I have no idea why.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

[image]

Comment: the last bind-Value is wrong. You can't bind to .ToString()

Comment: @gsharp Yes sir.  That solved the error messages.  If you put that as an answer, will be more than glad to accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last bind-Value is wrong. You can't bind to `.ToString()`.

`bind-*` enables two way binding, therefore the bound item needs to be "writable" like a property or a field.